# UITableView background image problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am using UITableView.I set the tableview background image like this.

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
```

[image]

I am using table style as grouped. But in display I am getting black shadow on left and right side of grouped cell.

How to remove this black shadow?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: are you set property before setting color clearclor

Comment: No, I did not use clearcolor property.

Comment: try first clear color then set above return code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this..

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample2.png"];
UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:backgroundImage]; 
self.tableView.backgroundView=backgroundImageView;
[backgroundImageView release];
```

Answer (score 1):

First, set the background image for the table's parent view to the image that you want:

```
[parentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
```

Then, set the background image for the UITableView to clearColor:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

That should solve the problem.

Comment: This works great if you don't want the background image/view to stretch if the table view is resized

Answer (score 0):

You can use these lines instead of the above line to get rid of black color :

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.jpg"];   
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:backgroundImage];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundView];  
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the opaque property to `NO`:

```
[self.tableView setOpaque: NO];
```

Comment: I am still having the problem after setting setOpaque to No

Comment: is the controller a `UITableViewController`, or a `UIViewController`?

Comment: It is a UITableViewController

Answer (score 0):

Set the tableview's backgroundColor to clearColor and set the tableview's backgroundView to nil and it will show the color of the view on which it was added on to. And if your tableview is a standalone grouped style table view controller, then set its opaque property to NO.